# Pandas sort the year per decade with relative sum

Tags: pandas, analytics

```
ar["year"] = ar["Date"].dt.year
ar.groupby("year")["Operator"].size().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

I have this result

[image]

how I can sort by decade with the relative sum?

Comment: For clarification: What do you mean by "sort by decade with the relative sum"? Do you mean "group by decade" and then see per decade, what is the sum of the second column?

Comment: try `ar["Date"].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="10Y")).sum().Operator`